# ORA-06550: close symbol encountered

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  CURSOR 
  IS 
    SELECT SVL_ID 
      FROM SALES_VEHICLES 
     WHERE SVL_N = 'some value';--314653;

    TYPE SVD_TA IS TABLE OF VSALES%ROWTYPE;
    SV SVD_TA;
BEGIN
  OPEN VSALES;
  FETCH VSALES BULK COLLECT INTO SV LIMIT 1000;
  CLOSE VSALES;

  IF SV.COUNT() <> 0 
  THEN
    FOR I IN 1..SV.COUNT() 
    LOOP
       UPDATE SALES_VEHICLES
          SET SVL_M  = 'some value', 
              SVL_M  = SVL_C_N
        WHERE SVL_ID = I.SVL_ID;

       COMMIT;
     END LOOP;
   END IF;
   EXIT WHEN VSALES%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE VSALES;
END;
```

I having trouble debugging this. The error is at line 32, column 5. I would be immensely grateful if you can help me out with this issue.

Comment: You are closing the cursor twice. Once after retrieving it and once at the very end. But yhy are you using a cursor for this at all? The whole procedure can be replace with a single `update` statement - which will also be a **lot** faster then your slow row-by-row approach.

Comment: I have been asked to not use the single update statement. I tried closing the cursor only once and I am still get the ORA 06550 error.(encountered the symbol end)

Comment: No offence, but that is a stupid request. Why do something the slow and non-scalable way?

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to PL/SQL. My boss asked me to do this. Can you please tell me how can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if the cursor returns more than 1000 rows? Also, the `commit` should be outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have double close tthe same cursor in line 15 and 32.

Probably you don't want to close just after fetch.

```
BEGIN
  OPEN VSALES;
  LOOP
  FETCH VSALES BULK COLLECT INTO SV LIMIT 1000;

  IF SV.COUNT() <> 0 
  THEN
    FOR I IN 1..SV.COUNT() 
    LOOP
       UPDATE SALES_VEHICLES
          SET SVL_M  = 'some value', 
              SVL_M  = SVL_C_N
        WHERE SVL_ID = SV(I).SVL_ID;;

       COMMIT;
     END LOOP;
   END IF;
   EXIT WHEN VSALES%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE VSALES;
END;
```

Comment: I tried closing the cursor only once and I am still get the ORA 06550 error.(encountered the symbol end)

Comment: Because you have also two `end loop;` and only one `loop`. Probably you're missing loop after opening cursor @ishan

Comment: @ishan try that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was missing the following. Here's what I changed

FROM THIS:

```
 WHERE  SVL_ID    = I.SVL_ID;
```

TO THIS:

```
 WHERE  SVL_ID    = SV(I).SVL_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit more complicated than it needs to be. For a plain cursor loop, you could just do this:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select svl_id 
        from   sales_vehicles 
        where  svl_n = 'some value' --314653;
    )
    loop
        update sales_vehicles
        set    svl_m  = 'some value', svl_m  = svl_c_n
        where  svl_id = r.svl_id;
    end loop;

    commit;
end;
```

Or if you really want to use an array (and take the chance that it'll take more memory than you bargained for):

```
declare
    type svid_tt is table of sales_vehicles.svl_id%type;
    l_svids svid_tt;
begin
    select svl_id bulk collect into l_svids
    from   sales_vehicles 
    where  svl_n = 'some value';--314653;

    if l_svids.count > 0 then
        forall i in 1..l_svids.count 
            update sales_vehicles
            set    svl_m  = 'some value', svl_m  = svl_c_n
            where  svl_id = l_svids(i);
    end if;

    commit;
end;
```

You could make the array version more robust by adding a limit clause and a loop, and checking for bulk exceptions etc.